# Unexpected number of decimals result from integer division SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get total amount using the following query

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity * UnitPrice * (Discount/100)) 
FROM Stock_Purchase_Details
```

My table structure

```
Proid | unitprice | discountrate(inpercentage) | proqty
1     |  10.00    | 10.00                      |  10
2     |  10.00    | 10.00                      |  10
```

I expect the total amount to be  20.00, but the query I used returns this result `20.00000000` - why is that?

Comment: The values are the same.  You can cast to a decimal if you only want to see two decimal places.

Comment: 20.00 and 20.00000000 and 20 are equal, btw.

Comment: What are the **datatypes** of your columns??

Comment: CAST the output to decimal(13,2) for example to a number with 2 digit as decimal points

Comment: types unitprice discountrate(inpercentage) decimal (5,2)

Comment: 20.00 = 20.00000000000.    The rest is just output formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(Quantity * UnitPrice * (Discount/100)) AS DECIMAL(4,2)) 
FROM Stock_Purchase_Details
```

Answer (score 6):

The comments describe well enough that the result is correct and what you can do to get the result in the format you require (just cast it to the datatype required: `CONVERT(decimal(5, 2), calculation)`).

**Why**, I feel, has not been answered, and that was your actual question. 
You are dividing a `decimal(5, 2)` with an `integer`. SQL server implicitly casts the divisor (`100`) to the datatype of the dividend (`decimal(5,2)`), because the datatypes have to match, and `decimal` takes [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) over an `integer`. The output of the division is also a `decimal`, but the precision and scale are [calculated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx). The output scale is `max(6, scale of dividend + precision of divisor + 1)` = `max(6, 2 + 5 + 1)`. So you end up with a scale of `8`, hence the 8 zeroes.

In fact, the end result is a `DECIMAL(13, 8)`, to be perfectly complete.